# Reference 'fig:01_01' on page 1 undefined

Tags: floats, ref

I'm writing my thesis and I've founded some problems with refer a figure. For example, in the below code, I have a `main.tex` and I call other chapters with input or include (e.g. ch1). In the "ch1" I inserted a figure and `\ref` before, when I compile, the reference shows "Figure ??" with questions marks instead of the number of the figure. I already checked if keep the same name in the \ref and `\label`. Please, I appreciate any help with this.

Note: May be the problem is works with "main.tex", since I tried writting the chapter in the same archive, and I haven't problem, I don't know why. I would like works with the structured form.

```
\documentclass[10pt,oneside,onecolumn]{book}

\usepackage{geometry} %margenes

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} %tildes

\usepackage{setspace} %paquete para interlineado

\usepackage{helvet} % para tipo de letra

\usepackage{ragged2e} %alineamiento del texto horizontal

\usepackage{indentfirst} %borrar o establecer sangrías

\usepackage{graphicx} %imágenes

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} %LaTeX asocia el caracter "228" y lo transforma en el requerido

\usepackage{fancyhdr} %formatos paginas header & footer

\usepackage{imakeidx}

\usepackage{titlesec} %editor de titulo

\usepackage[labelfont=bf]{caption} % poner negrita la palabra "figura" en imágenes

\usepackage{subcaption} %Crear subfiguras

\usepackage{caption} %Crear subfiguras


 \geometry{letterpaper,
  total={151mm,214mm},
  left=40mm,
  top=40mm,
  }

\begin{document}

\input{ch1}
\input{ch2}

\end{document}

%%%%%%

\chapter{\Large{ %tamaño 14
    \textbf{\parindent=0pt  % negrita
    Introduccion}
   }
  }
\normalsize{\parindent=0pt
Este es el cap\'itulo n\'umero uno de esta tedioso y larga tesis.
}

\section{Cualquier cosa}
\parindent=0pt

Hola Figure~\ref{fig:01_01}

\begin{figure}[ht]
\centering

\includegraphics[scale=0.2]{Imagenes/01_01}
\caption{Comite de ciencia 2012.\label{fig:01_01}}

\end{figure}
```

Comment: Have you tried compiling your document _twice_?

Comment: Off-topic: (i) If you didn't load the `indentfirst` package, you wouldn't have to supply all those `\parindent=0pt` (=`\noindent`) instructions after chapter- and section-level headers. (ii) `\Large` is a switch, i.e., it doesn't take an argument encased in curly braces.